# What html form control is used in adding multiple value field?

Tags: html, forms

I have making a simple jsp app and i have a many to many relationship between song and genre. What form field should i use to add multiple genres to a song. I am thinking of check boxes but i don't know if it is appropriate. Here is my erd.[image: Song erd]

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to select multiple options, checkboxes would be the best option.

Radio and `<select>` would only select one.

[W3 Schools: `<input>` Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Answer (score 0):

A multi-select dropdown will suit best here. And I suggest Select2 (https://select2.github.io/) if you're using jQuery in your project.

Regarding manipulating the values, I suggest use JSON. You can get selected Genres from Select2 as an array. Just bind like this

```
[
    {
        "song": "<song_name>",
        "genres": "[select2 values in array]"
    },
    ..
]
```

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how to manipulate the value in jsp.